# Optimizing a long query (which uses order by rand() too)

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT picture_path, profile_picture, username FROM users
WHERE profile_picture IS NOT NULL
AND settings LIKE '1,%' 
AND  last_visit BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 DAY AND CURDATE() 
AND signup_date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 15");
```

This query can be slow, and I'd like to optimize it as much as possible.

Should I be indexing all fields used in this query (a multi index of them all together?)

Is ORDER BY RAND() most likely slowing the query a lot? What alternative would you recommend?

There are about 700,000 records in the DB.

When I explain the query, I get http://screencast.com/t/Opdx3fJ80

Comment: you should definitely be using indexes on your date columns to speed up the db. more info at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: when explaining the query, I get http://screencast.com/t/Opdx3fJ80 -- it seems to be using last_visit so far as an index.

Comment: To see if order by rand slowit or not, just try with and without

Comment: Only 1 index can be used at the same time, so there is no point indexing every column. Better create composite index.

Comment: I can definitely see a slight improvement without using ORDER BY RAND()

Comment: How many records do your WHERE criteria normally return (that is, before you use `LIMIT 15`)? `ORDER BY RAND()` will only be slowing your query, if there are many records that need to be ordered after the WHERE criteria have been applied. As @ArvindSridharan mentioned, it might be more fruitful to speed it up by indexing either settings, last_visit, signup_date or a combination of them.

Comment: @Dan - I see. Actually it returns only around 1000 records. 1000 records out of 700,000, so I believe indexing would be more fruitful as you said.

Comment: I also have another query where 'sex' is a criteria, but the only possible values for sex are 0 and 1. Should an index be created for settings, last_visit, signup_date, sex, or just settings, last_visit, signup_date

Comment: In general, it is pointless to add an index to a column, where filtering would return 50% of the records, or more. So for a sex-column where you expect an approximate 50/50 distribution of 0's and 1's, indexing would probably hurt more than it would gain.

Comment: Thank you. I will create a combined index for signup_date, last_visit, settings and see how it goes.

Comment: I've created an index, (CREATE INDEX signup_visit_settings ON users (signup_date, last_visit, settings), but the query is taking only the last_visit index (which was already created a while back). How come?

Comment: Also, would it be good to add profile_picture as an index too, even if I'm using "IS NOT NULL" ?